# How do I get objectValue for a cell in my custom cell class (subclass of NSTextFieldCell)?

Tags: cocoa

I have a custom NSOutlineView with a cell based structure.
I have hooked a custom cell for the outlineView.
For each row in the outline view, I have hooked a custom Data Model object for each Row in the outlineview.
I have hooked the node object using following methods:

- `(NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item`
- `(id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item`
- `(id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)theColumn byItem:(id)item`

Now I need to access the data Model object in my Custom Cell Class's `drawInteriorWithFrame::` method in order to draw it accordingly.

I tried using `[self objectValue]` in Custom Cell Class, but it does not return me the object I passed it as `ObjectValue`.

Is there anything wrong in my approach? Or is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what is happening with the objectValue of the cell. But one way to handle this would be to add a property or member variable to your Cell subclass to hold a reference to your model object. Then you can use that within drawInteriorWithFrame:. Be sure to nil the reference in dealloc if you are not using ARC.

Comment: Great, if you think this is the right answer then you could mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: I found a way to fix this by using custom Views for each cell, and mixed it with the solution provided by Jon. Now Each cell(which is a custom view) has a property holding up my model.